# Error running debug ios app in Flutter VScode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I recently installed and setted up flutter in macos. I installed all the flutter sdk and plugins in visual studio code. But i am facing error while testing the app. I already opened ios emulator and then try to run app by Flutter run. But it always fails and shows me below error. I have tried Flutter clean and flutter pub get many times. still no solution.

log output and error which i got in the terminal:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...

Running pod install...                                             21.6s
Running Xcode build...                                                  

 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                          24.1s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        15.9s
Xcode build done.                                           140.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-05-08 18:48 xcodebuild[2061] (FSEvents.framework) fsevent_realpath:
    err(2): [No such file or directory]

    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:22:27:
    warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
                        print((result as! FlutterError).message)
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:22:53:
    note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
                        print((result as! FlutterError).message)
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
                                                                ?? <#default
                                                                value#>
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:22:53:
    note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
                        print((result as! FlutterError).message)
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
                                                               !
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:22:53:
    note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
                        print((result as! FlutterError).message)
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
                                                                as Any
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:29:96:
    warning: treating a forced downcast to 'String' as optional will never
    produce 'nil'
                            let urlResponse = URLResponse(url: url, mimeType:
                            json["content-type"] as! String,
                            expectedContentLength: -1, textEncodingName:
                            json["content-encoding"] as! String)
                                                                                                   ^
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:29:98:
    note: use 'as?' to perform a conditional downcast to 'String'
                            let urlResponse = URLResponse(url: url, mimeType:
                            json["content-type"] as! String,
                            expectedContentLength: -1, textEncodingName:
                            json["content-encoding"] as! String)
                                                                                                     ^
                                                                                                     ?
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:29:75:
    note: add parentheses around the cast to silence this warning
                            let urlResponse = URLResponse(url: url, mimeType:
                            json["content-type"] as! String,
                            expectedContentLength: -1, textEncodingName:
                            json["content-encoding"] as! String)
                                                                              ^
                                                                              (
                                                                              )
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:29:178:
    warning: treating a forced downcast to 'String' as optional will never
    produce 'nil'
                            let urlResponse = URLResponse(url: url, mimeType:
                            json["content-type"] as! String,
                            expectedContentLength: -1, textEncodingName:
                            json["content-encoding"] as! String)
                                                                                                                                                                                     ^
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:29:180:
    note: use 'as?' to perform a conditional downcast to 'String'
                            let urlResponse = URLResponse(url: url, mimeType:
                            json["content-type"] as! String,
                            expectedContentLength: -1, textEncodingName:
                            json["content-encoding"] as! String)
                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
                                                                                                                                                                                       ?
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/CustomeSchemeHandler.swift:29:153:
    note: add parentheses around the cast to silence this warning
                            let urlResponse = URLResponse(url: url, mimeType:
                            json["content-type"] as! String,
                            expectedContentLength: -1, textEncodingName:
                            json["content-encoding"] as! String)
                                                                                                                                                            ^
                                                                                                                                                            (
                                                                                                                                                            )
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/FlutterWebViewController.swift:31:17:
    warning: result of call to 'parse(options:)' is unused
            options.parse(options: initialOptions)
                    ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/FlutterWebViewController.swift:87:46:
    warning: conditional downcast from 'String?' to 'String' does nothing
                let data = (initialData!["data"] as? String)!
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/FlutterWebViewController.swift:88:54:
    warning: conditional downcast from 'String?' to 'String' does nothing
                let mimeType = (initialData!["mimeType"] as? String)!
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/FlutterWebViewController.swift:89:54:
    warning: conditional downcast from 'String?' to 'String' does nothing
                let encoding = (initialData!["encoding"] as? String)!
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/FlutterWebViewController.swift:90:52:
    warning: conditional downcast from 'String?' to 'String' does nothing
                let baseUrl = (initialData!["baseUrl"] as? String)!
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/FlutterWebViewController.swift:252:41
    : warning: result of call to 'parse(options:)' is unused
                        inAppWebViewOptions.parse(options:
                        inAppWebViewOptionsMap)
                                            ^
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:2
    06:80: warning: coercion of implicitly unwrappable value of type 'UIView?'
    to 'Any' does not unwrap optional
            containerWebView_BottomFullScreenConstraint =
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.containerWebView, attribute:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                   ~
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:7
    5:19: note: implicitly unwrapped property 'containerWebView' declared here
        @IBOutlet var containerWebView: UIView!
                      ^
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:2
    06:85: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
            containerWebView_BottomFullScreenConstraint =
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.containerWebView, attribute:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                                                                                   ~~~~~^~~~~
                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                   ~
                                                                                                         ??
                                                                                                         <#default
                                                                                                         value#>
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:2
    06:85: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
            containerWebView_BottomFullScreenConstraint =
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.containerWebView, attribute:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                                                                                   ~~~~~^~~~~
                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                   ~
                                                                                                        !
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:2
    06:85: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
            containerWebView_BottomFullScreenConstraint =
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.containerWebView, attribute:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute:
            NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                                                                                   ~~~~~^~~~~
                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                   ~
                                                                                                         as Any
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    flutter_inappbrowser-2.0.2/ios/Classes/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:2
    07:77: warning: coercion of implicitly unwrappable value of type 'UIView?'
    to 'Any' does not unwrap optional
            containerWebView_TopFullScreenConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:
            self.containerWebView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.view,
            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, multiplier: 1,
            constant: 0)
                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~

                                                               ^
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    firebase_messaging-6.0.13/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:307:1:
    warning: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
    - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
    ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging
    .h:253:1: note: method 'messaging:didReceiveMessage:' declared here
    - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
    ^
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/fluterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
    firebase_messaging-6.0.13/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:309:63:
    warning: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [_channel invokeMethod:@"onMessage" arguments:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                                  ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging
    .h:226:62: note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData
    DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                 ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant
    Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter App/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
    mework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
    n.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFound
    ation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
    m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:17
    9:60: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
            #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                               ^
    6 warnings generated.
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.585 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366] Unable to
    get image dimensions for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-1024x1024@
    1x.png
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.639 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366] Unable to
    get image dimensions for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@1x.p
    ng
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.640 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366] Unable to
    get image dimensions for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@2x.p
    ng
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.641 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366] Unable to
    get image dimensions for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@2x.p
    ng
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.642 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366] Unable to
    get image dimensions for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@3x.p
    ng
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.643 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366] Unable to
    get image dimensions for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@1x.p
    ng
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.644 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366] Unable to
    get image dimensions for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@1x.p
    ng
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.645 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366] Unable to
    get image dimensions for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@2x.p
    ng
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.646 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366] Unable to

    2020-05-08 18:50:37.671 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage.png
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.672 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@3x.pn
    g
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.673 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage.png
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.674 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@3x.pn
    g
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.674 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@2x.p
    ng
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.675 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@2x.p
    ng
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.675 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38366]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@2x.p
    ng

    2020-05-08 18:50:37.734 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38424]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@2x.pn
    g
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.734 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38431]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@2x.pn
    g
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.734 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38391]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@3x.pn
    g
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.734 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38432]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage.png
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.735 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38431]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@2x.pn
    g
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.735 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38430]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@
    2x.png
    2020-05-08 18:50:37.735 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3010:38391]
    CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
    file:///Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant%20Flutter/Multi%20Restaurants%20Flu
    tter%20App/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@2x.p
    ng

    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@3x.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20~ipad.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon83.5x83.5@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/dhruv/Documents/Restaurant Flutter/Multi Restaurants Flutter
    App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Assets.car
    /Users/dhruv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guevtsknxqctmjaoseca
    mjyoltwv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runn
    er.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build
    descriptionwarning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function
    correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve
    this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner'
    from project 'Runner')warning: The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4
    mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test
    your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled,
    and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build
    setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target. (in target 'Runner' from
    project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone X.
```

I am completely new in flutter and have very little knowledge regarding the flutter apps. Had to delete some unuseful logs because it only allows to type 30000 words.

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/1288408) When you need urgent help, Stack Overflow is probably not the right place to look for it. People answering here are volunteers, this question has only been up for 4 hours (think of time zones, not every user is awake at this moment), and it is a weekend. Please be patient.

Comment: how did your solve this? i have the same problem.

Comment: @easazade try to update macos caltalina to a stable version. i think beta version have this error

Comment: I have the same problem with Catalina 10.15 beta on my virtualbox and xcode 11.3. Going to update to 10.15.4 and test with xcode 12

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your macos to a stable version. I think beta version have this error. Updating worked for me.